# Thread not getting garbage collected

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a situation where a thread with no references and in **NEW** state will not get garbage collected ?
Snippet from heap dump ( with live flag ) :

threadLocalRandomProbe (I) : 0

threadLocalRandomSecondarySeed (I) : 0

threadLocalRandomSeed (J) : 0

threadLocals (L) :

threadQ (L) :

threadStatus (I) : 0

tid (J) : 213

uncaughtExceptionHandler (L) :

References to this object:

Other Queries

Reference Chains from Rootset

Comment: GC collection doesn't have to happen immediately - are you sure you didn't just expect it to go immediately?   Having said that in the old days System.gc(); would definitely cause the garbage collector to run, so you would see things release that should be released. However, if you think about it - the underlying native thread is an expensive resource to get / allocate, so wouldn't you want to keep it around to re-use rather than throwing away [if you were the JVM implementer].

Comment: I took this heap dump using jmap with -dump:live flag and as per jmap documentation I'm assuming that it'll only keep objects which will not get GC'd i.e. which are live.

Comment: So what is the problem - you have 1 thread like this or are running out of threads because there are many?   1 - don't worry, but if you are ending up with lots hanging around, I would suspect something is holding onto it...   OR is it a daemon thread?  they are meant to hang around ..

Comment: It's not a demon thread and this thread is actually an object of inner class because of which it won't let even it's outer object to be GC'd ( can't change source code )

Comment: an inner class captures `this` of the outer class, implicitly. so that indeed might cause something like you describe. can you show the simplified code that you have?

Comment: It's like FOO creates an instance of BAR_OUTER and BAR_OUTER adds to shutdown hook an instance of BAR_INNER ( a subclass of thread ) . After x interval FOO may decide to dispose BAR_OUTER and calls BAR_OUTER's cleanup method which removes the shutdown hook. But for some reason this thread is not GC'd .

Comment: Try to provide a [mcve]